# Laptop ->TV via HDMI Adapter - audio static and feedback

Tags: laptop, hdmi, tv, adapter

I've connecting my laptop to a TV using an HDMI Adapter.

I am experiencing a audio feedback issue and hearing static and clicking while watching a movie.

OS is Vista, I have tried multiple HDMI cables with filter. 
Running a ViewSpan software that came with the HD/USB adapter. 
I was told that I may possibly need to set my audio for HDMI but cannot find where to change the settings.

Answer (score 1):

Are your cables shielded? It could be interference.  Move your cable around and if the noise patterns change as you move the cable then it is interference.

**Feedback is caused by a speaker to close to a microphone.**

Mute any microphones on your laptop.  For good measure you may want to mute all recording devices.

Comment: I Muted Microphone, and yet i have issues. the static/clicking is utters when my laptop is doing something. for instances moving mouse, streaming etc....